# datatable sorting not behaving correctly

Tags: jquery, datatables

I am using datatables to sort table on first load. It works fine for ids less than 100, but for ids greater than that it shows 98,99 above 112, 103 etc in desc format. This is my code:

```
$('#datatabable').dataTable({
    "aaSorting" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ],
    "iDisplayLength" : 5,
    "aLengthMenu" : [ [ 5, 10, 20, -1 ],
    [ 5, 10, 20, "All" ] ],
    "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers"
});
```

My ids are showing like this:

98

99

190

189

188

187

Am I writing correctly?

Comment: If you're using DataTables since 1.10, instead of `"aaSorting" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ],`, try `"order" : [ [ 2, "desc" ] ],`

Comment: Could you produce a fiddle to illustrate the problem? (There is http://live.datatables.net/ for easy building of DT-Samples...)